# Basic Java- Having trouble diplaying an array from a seperate method in main

Tags: java, arrays, methods, program-entry-point

*Edited- I fixed the code, I was completely off base with the original. This is the program I have now. It's intended to be a similar to a connect four game but instead of winning by connecting diagonally, horizontally or vertically. The only way to win is by connecting four Xs vertically. I'm now having trouble figuring out the code that could a win. Any ideas?

package stackemupnew;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackEmUpNew {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declares the game space array
    char[][] gameSpace = new char[6][6];
    int[] rowTrack = new int[]{5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};

    //prints number of columns above the board
    for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");

    }
    System.out.println(" ");

    //sets the game space to it's starting state
    for (int i = 0; i < gameSpace.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gameSpace[i].length; j++) {
            gameSpace[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < gameSpace.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gameSpace[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(gameSpace[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    //prints number of columns under the board
    for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");

    }
    System.out.println(" ");



    while (winDetector(gameSpace) == false) {

        //run the method that lets the user make a move
        userMove(gameSpace, rowTrack);
        for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");

    }
    System.out.println(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < gameSpace.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameSpace[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(gameSpace[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

     for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");

    }
    System.out.println(" ");

    //run the method that checks for a win
    winDetector(gameSpace);

        //run the method that makes a computer move
        computerMove(gameSpace, rowTrack);

        System.out.println("The computer's move is:");

        for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");

    }
    System.out.println(" ");


        for (int i = 0; i < gameSpace.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameSpace[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(gameSpace[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");

    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    }
    winDetector(gameSpace);
}

//detects a win NOT FINISHED
public static boolean winDetector(char[][] gameSpace){ 
 boolean win = false;   
    for (int i = 0; i < gameSpace.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameSpace[i].length; j++){
                if (gameSpace[i][j]=='X'&&
                    gameSpace[i][j+1]=='X'&&
                    gameSpace[i][j+2]=='X'&&
                    gameSpace[i][j+3]=='X'){
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! You win!");
                    win = true;
                }
            }
    }
return win;
}

public static void userMove(char[][] gameSpace, int[] rowTrack) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Where would you like to drop an X?");

    int col = input.nextInt();
    int row = rowTrack[col];

    rowTrack[col]--;

    gameSpace[row][col] = 'X';
}

public static void computerMove(char[][] gameSpace, int[] rowTrack) {

    int col = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    int row = rowTrack[col];

    rowTrack[col]--;

    gameSpace[row][col] = 'O';
}
```

}

```
 The output reads:
 0 1 2 3 4 5  
 . . . . . . 
 . . . . . . 
 . . . . . . 
 . . . . . . 
 . . . . . . 
 . . . . . . 
 0 1 2 3 4 5  
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at stackemupnew.StackEmUpNew.winDetector(StackEmUpNew.java:107)
    at stackemupnew.StackEmUpNew.main(StackEmUpNew.java:48)
 Java Result: 1
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: what is the output you expect?

Comment: This code is not even going to compile.

Comment: You are not passing any argument to method call.. How this code is even getting compiled?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add the brackets if you intend to call `gameSpaceInitial()`.

```
System.out.println(gameSpaceInitial());
```

Second, a variable defined as char[][] is an array of char arrays. So for the following code:

```
gameSpace = new char[6][6];
```

... the value of `gameSpace.length` should be 6.

Third, your `gameSpaceInitial` method needs to return gameSpaceInitial, but without the extra '}' in your code.

Fourth, If you pass a `char[][]` to `System.out.println()`, you will see the memory reference of the `char[][]`, not the contents.

Answer (score 0):

The method `gameSpaceInitial(int i,int j)` accepts two int type parameters. You are forgetting to pass them.

You need to do something like,

`System.out.println(gameSpaceInitial(2,3));`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're only printing the length of `gameSpace`. This does not include the number of elements in the array values.

```
public class StackEmUp {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        char[][] gameSpace = gameSpaceInitial( 6, 6 );

        int rows = gameSpace.length;
        System.out.println( "Rows: " +  rows );

        int elements = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
            elements += gameSpace[i].length;
        }

        System.out.println( "Elements: " + elements );
        ...
    }

    private static char[][] gameSpaceInitial ( int rows, int cols ) {
        char[][] gameSpaceInitial = new char[rows][cols];

        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) {
                gameSpaceInitial[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }

        return gameSpaceInitial;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here are totally correct. Everyone is touching on parts of your code that need fixing however it all needs to be combined, plus a few additional things fixed up.

See this fiddle for corrections to make it work:
http://ideone.com/ga62vf

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int i=6;
    int j=6;

    //initialize the array
    char[][] gameSpace; 
    gameSpace = gameSpaceInitial(i, j);

    //display the initial game space
    DisplayGameSpace(gameSpace);
}

//the intial game board without any pieces
static char[][] gameSpaceInitial(int maxRows,int maxColumns){

    char[][] emptyBoard = new char[maxRows][maxColumns];

    for (int row = 0; row < maxRows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < maxColumns; col++) {
            emptyBoard[row][col] = '.';
        }
    }

    return emptyBoard;   
}
```

So to explain what this fixes in your code:

```
char[][] gameSpace; 
gameSpace = new char[i][j];
```

This just creates an empty 2D array. You then need to populate it with the values you want (the `.`'s). What you want to do is call the `gameSpaceInitial` method to assign the empty game board to `gameSpace`.
When you call `gameSpaceInitial` you have defined two parameters that need to be passed to it, or your code will not compile. In your example it is expecting two `int`s `i` and `j`. I have renamed them to give them more meaning and make the code readable. Then what you do is loop through each row and then each column filling it with the desired character. We then return this new char array and it will be assigned to `gameSpace`.

Then to make display of the board easier I have added an additional method that does the same double loop through the rows and columns to print each character:

```
static void DisplayGameSpace(char[][] gameSpace) {
    for (int row = 0; row < gameSpace.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < gameSpace[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(gameSpace[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```